# Is it possible to make a metric describing a non-stationary system?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

I know from the Schwarzschild metric that it is a stationary solution to einstein`s equations described by its metric. But what if I have a spacetime that evolves with time? Can I build a metric to describe it?

Comment: Sure. For example, the Friedmann metric for an expanding (or contracting), homogeneous, and isotropic universe has explicit time-dependence in the form of the scale factor $a(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

The term "static" in the context of general relativity means both that it does not evolve with time and that it is irrotational.  In that respect, even the well-known Kerr spacetime is not static, although it is *stationary*.

Any spacetime with gravitational waves, for example, will not even be stationary.  These spacetimes have a well-defined metric, although in complicated cases you may need to "build" it through a numerical simulation and in many cases, when done analytically, it is usually constructed via perturbation theory around some other known metric.

Comment: I think I meant stationary, i will edit the question for a better answer.

Comment: Either way, the answer covers both static and stationary.

Comment: What about a hard non-stationary? (not considering gravitational waves, but for example a mass parameter which its density/position evolves with time)

Comment: Every spacetime is described by a solution to the Einstein equations. If you're willing to have a stress-energy tensor and not worry about what type of matter it represents, you can take *any* metric, compute its Einstein tensor, and call the "leftover" a stress-energy tensor.  What do you really want to know? I feel like your question is something different than what you've asked.

Comment: Im trying to build the metric of a non-stationary system. The question arised because I know black holes metrics describe a stationary solution.

Comment: Then you should post a new question with details of the metric that you're trying to build. At this level of generality, the only answer to the question that you've asked can be "yes".